# How do you extract an attribute value from and element with iMacros?

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

I'm trying to record a macro that can extract a value from a target element.

This is what I tried... but it didn't work :(

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:foo EXTRACT=ARIA-EXPANDED
```

I also [saw some docs](http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#Extract_Custom_Attributes) that made it look like this would work:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:foo&&ARIA-EXPANDED:* EXTRACT=ARIA-EXPANDED
```

No luck so far...

Answer (score 2):

You may try like so:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:foo&&ARIA-EXPANDED:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET attr EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/aria-expanded=[\"'](.+?)[\"']/)[1];")
```

Comment: I guess you have to just be careful as to how big that html blob is? Seems like this could be heavy. Any idea how well iMacros handles memory if the element is huge?

Comment: Do you mean that the html-code of your 'div'-element is huge?